# align and flalign in a same document

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Test
\begin{align}
a+b=c
\end{align}
Test
\begin{flalign}
a+b=c
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

And the output shows:

[image]

Both equations comes as center alignment, but I required the second equation should be in flush left with 24pt indent. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Please do not create new tags that will not help anyone else (only those that are really reusable which `flaigh` isn't). Instead, use the default tags that cover your question best.

Comment: `fl` in `flalign` does not mean "flush left" it means "full length" also why are you using either environment if you have no alignment points (`&`) ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reason, but…

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
Test
\begin{align}
a+b=c
\end{align}
Test
\begin{fleqn}[24pt]
\begin{align}
a+b=c
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you know that `align` should not be used for single equations.